# mongodb: Unique index on encrypted field

Tags: node.js, mongodb, security, encryption

I'm encrypting SSNs in mongodb. However, I need to use the SSN as a unique identifier to make sure that a person with that SSN does not insert a duplicate. So basically I want to check for duplicate SSNs before saving. However I'm unsure if I'll be able to do this after encrypting this field with an AES function. If I encrypt and sign 2 strings which are identical with AES, will the output still be identical?

If not, what would be a good alternative? I had thought about hashing the SSN, but an SSN seems to have such little entropy(its 9 numeric digits, some of which are somewhat predictable). If I salt, I lose the ability to assign a unique index on that field, unless I use a static salt which doesn't really do much.

**Addition**

I would be encrypting at the application level using the node.js crypto core module.

Comment: Sounds like you need to "pad" the ecrypted data with something unique. You might look at the MongoDB [ObjectId](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/) for inspiration here, adding things like the truncated timestamp and some random data. Just be aware of the byte positioning and split it out when you decrypt.

Comment: Encrypted data shouldn't need to be padded. Only the hash data is where entropy would be an issue. With hash you crack for its containing value, with an encryption you'd need the key to actual confirm its contents. The encryption key has very strong entropy. My primary concern is whether or not 2 identical strings will remain identical after being encrypted with AES.

Comment: Would it feasible to use an *additional* field just to hold a simple checksum?

Comment: That's what I mentioned. Storing a checksum with a hash would be very easily cracked because there is such little entropy. There are 9 numeric digits in an SSN, some of these digits are not random and can be guessed. Its my understanding that certain SSN digits signify time and location. So there aren't very many combinations, which makes it relatively easy to crack.

Comment: I'm open to using another field to store some sort of checksum, but generating the checksum would pose a security risk. I'm wondering how to mitigate this, or if I even need to.

Comment: Perhaps you could use a field containing just *one* digit of your SSNs, as a kind of error correction.  However, is AES a must-have?  If you are unsure whether AES encryption is an *injective* function, would it be possible to switch to another encryption scheme?

Comment: There is no reason to use AES other than its a very common and strong encryption standard. I'm willing to use any mature crypto function.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by storing a single digit. I need to be able to ensure that SSN doesn't already exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the same symmetric AES key to encipher 2 identical strings will produce an identical output. Therefore you can identify whether or not the encrypted field is unique by comparing it to a value enciphered with the same key.

PoC:

```
var crypto = require('crypto');

var cipher = crypto.createCipher('aes-256-ctr', "someString");
var cipher2 = crypto.createCipher('aes-256-ctr', "someString");

var crypted = cipher.update("hello world",'utf8','hex');
var crypted2 = cipher2.update("hello world",'utf8','hex');

crypted === crypted2 //true
```